# how to bind the model to view from viewmodel in windows phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

I am creating an application using MVVM model. My application is a PanoramaApplication with 2 panoramaItemTemplates.
I have crated a view, viewmodel and model folders and have `Item.xaml` and `Item1ViewModel.cs`,`Item2ViewModel`  and `Item1Model.cs`,`Item2Model.cs` files respectively in those folders.

In the veiw `Item.xaml` I have the following controls:
When the user clicks the button "GetDetails" in the PanoramaItem1 page I will display the values for `ReadOperationStatus`, `DateOfRegistration` and `PointsEarned`, `LastTimePlayed` ,`Name` in `PanoramaItem2` page.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <phone:Panorama Title="AccountDetails">

        <!--Panorama item one-->
        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="item1">
            <Grid>

                <TextBox Text="{Binding EmailId}"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding MobileNumber}"></TextBox>
                <Button Content="GetDetails" Command="{Binding GetDetailsClickCommand}"></Button>
                <TextBlock text="{Binding ReadOperationStatus}"/>
                <TextBlock text="{Binding DateOFRegistration}"/>
            </Grid>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>

        <!--Panorama item two-->
        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="item2">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PointsEarned}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastTimePlayed}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
    </phone:Panorama>
</Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

My Model classes have the following code in them:

```
public class Item1Model
{
    public Item1Model()
    {
    }

    public string EmailID { get; set; }
    public int MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string REadOperationStatus{ get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfRegistration { get; set; }
}

public class Item2Model
{
    public Item2Model()
    {
    }

    public int PointsEarned { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastPlayed { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The ViewModels have the following code:

```
class Item1ViewModel:InotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Item1ViewModel()
    {
    }

    public System.Windows.Input.ICommand GetDetailsClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new DelegateCommand((o) =>
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    GetPlayerDetails();
                });
            });
        }
    }

    public static GetPlayerDetails()
    {
        //i want to access EmailID,MobileNumber which are inputs to the service method
        //here i connect to a service and wait for the event DetailsDownload_Completed.
    }

    private void DetailsDownload_Completed(DetailsOwner sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        //here i get  args.PointsEarned, args.LAstPlayed,args.Name ,
        //which i want to bind them to the respective peroperties in the panoramaitem1,panoramaitem2
    }
}

class Item2ViewModel
{
    public Item2ViewModel ()
    {
        //currently i dont have anything here
    }
}

the questions I have is how do I read the values of EMail, Mobilenumber which user has enterd in UI. And how do I set the values back in UI once I read the values from service..I want to know how should the binding be here..
```

Do I need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged also in the Model ?

Any help with the code would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the point of MVVM ...

Your View should NOT bind or care or know about your model.

The INotifyProperty is used to let the binding know something has changed.

Ideally your model will do it's logic stuff ... The ViewModel will have the properties that you'll be binding to on the View, and they will have the notification change interface.

If you're binding straight to your Model, you're violating the whole purpose of MVVM (and you can get rid of the ViewModel since you're not using it as you should).

Having said that, if you'll search around, you'll see some people will implement the INPC interface in the Model, and no kittens will be killed for that.

Comment: Glad it was helpful ... involved lots of reading :) . You could upvote it you find it useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the model must implement INotifyPropertyChanged if you want to bind directly to the Model instead of the ViewModel.

Comment: Then in the ViewModel GetDetailsClickCommand how do I read the values EmailID,MobileNumber  which are set in UI?

Comment: The UI binds to the model, the view model manages the model. In your VM, you should have a model property which keeps track of the model (there needs to be a way to expose the model to the view anyway). See https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Different+interpretations+of+MVVM, you are using the "shortcut interpretation".